# When running sequence job in datastage, get the timeout error ,code =-14 [Timed out while waiting for an event]

Tags: sequence, datastage

When running sequence job in Datastage, there would be occasions to get error like this：

**Seq_CHECK_JV_OMS_DATA..JobControl (@Pjob_CHECK_JV_OMS_DATA): Controller problem: Error calling DSRunJob(Pjob_CHECK_JV_OMS_DATA.Seq_CHECK_JV_OMS_DATA), code=-14
[Timed out while waiting for an event]**

Why would this happen? Cause I'm not running these job instances concurrently, but execute one by one (It is serializable)?

**And I get other problems too. The job instances under sequence job controller often get stuck like this:**

[image]

And this status will last for ever unless I clear the status file

I'm getting crazy with that! Could anyone help? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your server is **overloaded**, and after 60 seconds it stops and abort with this error, when you try to execute your job *Pjob_CHECK_JV_OMS_DATA.Seq_CHECK_JV_OMS_DATA*. Do you have many instances of the job *Pjob_CHECK_JV_OMS_DATA* running at the same time?

Try to wait a few seconds to start this job.